# Getting an AttributeError when trying to install pip using ensurepip on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm trying to install pandas to do some scripting on my macbook, but I'm running into this error:

`AttributeError: partially initialized module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'terminate' (most likely due to a circular import)`

I'm using python 3.10, installed using brew. I tried installing pip with `python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade`, and by running `brew postinstall python3` (both gave the same error).

I've tried reinstalling python + updating brew packages. Python itself seems to be behaving normally, I'm able to run some of the other scripts I've written.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you simply create a virtual environment using `python3 -m env my_virtual_env`? (`venv` installs `pip` for you in the environment, I think using `ensurepip`.)

Comment: Just tried setting that up, and it seems to have worked? Using the pip3 file within the folder that command created seemed to install the package fine, was able to import pandas after running the python3 from that folder as well.
(I have no previous experience using venv in python)

Comment: Okay yeah this venv is working with pandas, I'll just use this for my scripting for now and look into the rest of the issue later. Thanks for the help!